# Dataframes: Percentage of time when a value matches a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Considering the following DataFrame where on the first column we have the time(microseconds) since the system was started and on the second one any other value.
How can I find for how much time (percentage from total) the value from the second column matches a certain condition?

```
161.269965    0.018142
161.470018    0.021820
161.670710    0.073925
161.871526    0.020144
162.105240    0.042607
162.337896    0.042966
162.538761    0.047488
162.771496    0.048468
163.004352    0.056527
163.205215    0.039028
163.437925    0.050128
163.638910    0.053168
163.868374    0.028917
164.069121    0.075242
164.269928    0.063719
164.502714    0.028207
...

726.498849    0.076954
```

For the DataFrame above how can I find for how much (percentage from total) time the value from the second column was over `0.4`?

Comment: Assuming the column you're considering is called `"value"`: `df["value"].gt(0.4).mean()`

Answer (score 0):

```
(df[df.columns[1]] > 0.4).mean()
```

Create a Series that's True when your column is greater than .4 and False otherwise. Since True = 1 and False = 0, we can then just take the average value to find the portion that's True.